# How can i make a video play at the timestamp is was previously paused at?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i have a programm where you have a listview of items (img or video) and if you clikc on on item a new view opens where you see the details of the clicked item.

I want to play a video at the timestamp it was previously paused at, even if the Browser was updated/ reloaded.

this is what i tried but it is not working after i reload the browser or change the view the video starts at the start/ 0

````
const currentVideo = this.root.querySelector("#video");
        var played;
        currentVideo.addEventListener("click", function() {
            if(currentVideo.play()) {
                 played = currentVideo.currentTime;
            }
            else if (currentVideo.pause()){
                localStorage.setItem("timestamp", played);

                if (currentVideo.play()){
                    localStorage.getItem(played);
                    currentVideo.currentTime = played;

                }
            }```
````

Comment: `if(currentVideo.play())` - you are not testing _if_ the video is currently playing here, but you are triggering it _to_ play.

Comment: so i need to change it to (!currentVideo.paused)? even then it is not setting the currentTime for the video :/,

Comment: is the problem that the program can't or don't know how to identify a specific video?

Comment: So, basically you want to *save* the timestamp to play the same video again at the last point you left of when refreshing the page?

Comment: Yes! that's what i want. But i need it to be for each video individually

Comment: I'd recommend opening a different question for making it applicable for multiple video's, but we can surely help you out with the storing/playing part.

Comment: That would be amazing thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looking for the timestamp where somebody paused, progressively update the last timestamp by listening for the [`timeupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event) event on the video element. This will ensure that the stored timestamp is at the last known position the video was playing.

```
const currentVideo = this.root.querySelector("#video");

// Check if a timestamp was stored and apply it if found.
const storedTimestamp = localStorage.getItem('videotimestamp');
if (storedTimestamp !== null) {
  const timestamp = Number.parseFloat(storedTimestamp);
  currentVideo.currentTime = timestamp;
}

// Update the last known timestamp when the video is playing.
currentVideo.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
  localStorage.setItem('videotimestamp', currentVideo.currentTime);
});

// Start playing.
currentVideo.play().catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

If you need more finegrained control, then there is also the [`play`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play_event), [`pause`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/pause_event), and many more events that you can use to know what your media is doing.

As for storing multiple timestamps for multiple videos: instead of storing a single timestamp, you could store an object where the keys are the IDs of the videos and the value the timestamp of the video, like so:

```
{
  video420: 1200.32,
  video69: 5230.89,
  video1337: 48.99
}
```

Then based on the ID of the video you could retrieve and update the timestamp you need.

Comment: Thank you so much ! It works like a charm :) i also changed the key to the item id like you said and that is also working